# How to Restrict type of data in iso message field

Tags: java, parsing, xml-parsing, iso8583, jpos

I am trying to parse an iso-8583 message.

I want to know how can we restrict the type of data being entered in the field.

for eg:
Lets say I have an iso message which has F48.1, and I want that F48.1 should only contain numbers and not characters.
I am using IFA_NUMERIC class provided by jpos but it does not seem to work. It is accepting all kinds of value.
If it contains characters, it should fail the parsing. How can this be done using xml schema file ?

Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this ?

This is my xml schema (Not adding all fields as schema is very big)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE isopackager PUBLIC
        "-//jPOS/jPOS Generic Packager DTD 1.0//EN"
        "http://jpos.org/dtd/generic-packager-1.0.dtd">

<!-- ISO 8583:1987 (ASCII) field descriptions for GenericPackager -->

<isopackager>
  <isofield
      id="0"
      length="4"
      name="MESSAGE TYPE INDICATOR"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="1"
      length="16"
      name="BIT MAP"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BITMAP"/>
  <isofield
      id="2"
      length="19"
      name="PAN - PRIMARY ACCOUNT NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
      id="3"
      length="6"
      name="PROCESSING CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="4"
      length="12"
      name="AMOUNT, TRANSACTION"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="36"
      length="104"
      name="TRACK 3 DATA"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="37"
      length="12"
      name="RETRIEVAL REFERENCE NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="47"
      length="999"
      name="ADITIONAL DATA - NATIONAL"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofieldpackager
      id="48"
      length="999"
      name="ADITIONAL DATA - PRIVATE"
      emitbitmap="false"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLBINARY">
       
       <isofield
      id="1"
      length="12"
      name="Sender Fee"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  </isofieldpackager>
  <isofield
      id="49"
      length="3"
      name="CURRENCY CODE, TRANSACTION"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="50"
      length="3"
      name="CURRENCY CODE, SETTLEMENT"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

We typically check the content of each field on the higher level application, at 'set' time. At some point, we had a contributed 'ValidatingPackager', but didn't get traction with the community. Thing is the same ISOMsg can be packed with different packagers, depending on the outgoing channel.

That said, it's in the roadmap to add the ability to validate content at the ISOMsg level.

Comment: Hi @apr, thanks for your response. I am using a generic packager to pack and unpack the message. But using Validating Packager can we restrict the data type ? Besides validating packager and checking data in high level application, we don't have any other way to check the data type before unpacking it?